# How to increase max length of acceptable url for ktor?

Tags: kotlin, netty, ktor

Now I have ktor server is based on netty.
When I do to long GET request (about 9300 characters (mostly in query params)), ktor answers `Unhandled: GET - /bad-request`.
If I reduce length of url, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your embedded server config you can provide a function “httpServerCodec” to create HttpServerCodec (https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpServerCodec.html) in which you can set the maxInitialLineLength property.

```
embeddedServer(Netty, configure = {
    // Size of the queue to store [ApplicationCall] instances that cannot be immediately processed
    requestQueueLimit = 16 
    // Do not create separate call event group and reuse worker group for processing calls
    shareWorkGroup = false 
    // User-provided function to configure Netty's [ServerBootstrap]
    configureBootstrap = {
        // ...
    } 

    httpServerCodec = {
       HttpServerCodec(.......)
    }
    // Timeout in seconds for sending responses to client
    responseWriteTimeoutSeconds = 10 
}) {
    // ...
}.start(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use your `application.conf` and increase `maxInitialLineLength` from default 4096:

```
ktor {
    deployment {
        ...
        maxInitialLineLength = 20000
    }
    application {
        ...
        maxInitialLineLength = 20000
    }
}
```